# Every Program is executed in terminal windows when opened using run dialog

Tags: xfce

I am facing a strange problem with my laptop, I have ubuntu 12.04 installed with xfce4 as the desktop. Whenever I open any new program like firefox by typing firefox in run dialog window, it opens a terminal in the background.

please refer this screenshot.

[image]

Has anybody else faced this problem earlier? I was not able to find a similar kind of issue anywhere else. By the way,im using xfce4.8 as desktop? is this issue with xfce desktop?

Comment: no im not running firefox &(background), whenever i open a run dialog using alt+f2 and execute any program, a new terminal window is opened as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Also, if I close the terminal window, the program(firefox) will get closed.

Comment: i am using xfwm4

Comment: I installed through 12.04 mainline and added the xubutnu-desktop. I cannot replicate this issue.  When I launch with `firefox &` through alt-f2 I do get a `www.&.com` couldn't be resolved error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you check the "Run in terminal" box when hitting <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>.
The change is persistent meaning that if you check it by accident, or use it on purpose the setting will remain next time you bring up the run dialog.

The purpose for this is to make the program run from a terminal so you can monitor output or possible errors put out by the program, also closing the terminal running the program will also close the program.

To fix just uncheck that box, shown here-

[image]

If this action is still hapening but the check box appears not to be checked try these steps-

1. Try checking the run in terminal box
2. Run a program
3. Bring run in terminal back up and try to uncheck it again
4. Run a program

This might be the results of one of two problems

Either the theme for the check is not working or this bug may be relevant -  http://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-bugs/2007-January/003075.html

Comment: magically it worked!!!! seems that is the issue , the run in terminal checkbox value is cached and is not refreshed properly. thanks @matthew

Comment: awarding bounty for finding that issue in xfce mailing list :)